# How return the type of polymorphic relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, active-model-serializers

I have a `participant` model that return a polymorphic relationship called `participable`, I need return the type of relationship instead of type `participable`. I am using at frontend Ember.

```
class ParticipantSerializer < ApplicationSerializer # :nodoc:
  attributes :id

  belongs_to :dispute
  belongs_to :participable, polymorphic: true
end
```

Comment: `participant.participable_type`

Comment: or `attributes :id, :participable_type`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case the issue is not with the polymorphic association, is with the app logic.

I fix it creating another associations through `participants`:

```
has_many :participants
has_many :users, through: :participants, source: :participable, source_type: 'User'
has_many :mediators, through: :participants, source: :participable, source_type: 'Mediator'
```

I hope this help.